# Inno setup check if the user has admin privileges

Tags: inno-setup

My installer should check at the beginning if the user has admin rights but It doesn't seem to work. With both boolean values for MyProgChecked , I don't get the prompt

```
    function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
var
    i: LongInt;
    hWnd: LongInt;
    IsUpdate: boolean;
    bCancel: boolean;
    CallName: string;
  MyProgChecked: boolean;

     begin
     MyProgChecked := not (IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn);    
     if MyProgChecked = true then
               MsgBox( 'Some message....', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    for i := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
        if uppercase(ParamStr(i)) = '/UPDATE' then
        begin
      ........
```

Comment: That does not make any sense. The code is correct. And works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mh4a.png - How do you even run the installer without administrator privileges? Do you set the [`PrivilegesRequired=lowest`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired)?

Comment: When I run the setup exe file, it installs properly in Stanfard user account and I can see in the log

Comment: Add this to the beginning on the `InitializeSetup`: `Log(Format('IsAdminLoggedOn = %d, IsPowerUserLoggedOn = %d', [IsAdminLoggedOn, IsPowerUserLoggedOn]));` - And show us a complete log.